# using the NOT IN operator on a column with NULL values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table `employee` which has a column company which has all null values

Now, I want to use a `NOT IN` operator for the company name as

```
select * from employee where employee.company NOT IN ('ABC', 'DEF')
```

Now technically this should not alter the result since the company column already had null values.

But adding the `NOT IN` gives 0 rows.

Is this due to the fact that `employee.company` column has `NULL` values?

Comment: If I'm correct, you'll need to use 'NOT EXISTS' instead of NOT IN.

Comment: FYI - Null is not a value like 'ABC', 001 etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select * 
from employee E
where (E.company NOT IN ('ABC', 'DEF')
       or E.company is null)
```

Answer (score 5):

SQL uses [three valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#SQL): `true`, `false`, and `unknown`.  A comparison with `null` results in `unknown`, which is not `true`.

So a `where` clause like:

```
where null in (1,2)
```

Will not return any rows.

Comment: "unknown, which is not true" - but "not true" IS false, by definition. :)

Comment: @mbeckish, unknown is by definition not true. is it by definition not false either. The headache disappears once you understand that this should not be understood under bool's laws because there are 3 bits, not 2.

Comment: @Sebas - Even in [Three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#SQL), "not true" is "false".  "unknown" is not defined as "not true".

Comment: @ypercube - No, because if "UNKNOWN IS NOT TRUE" is true, then that implies "UNKOWN IS FALSE".

Comment: @mbeckish I think what Andomar meant was not `unknown == !true` but `unknown != true`. Pure grammar, nothing to do with logic in this case.

Comment: @Sebas - Well, if you involve type comparison, then you are moving out of logic and into category theory.

Comment: @mbeckish I'm sorry I didn't intend to involve types. I'm editing to clarify.

Comment: @Sebas - I know, that's why I put the smiley face on my original comment.  Just pointing out that it's very tricky to explain these finer points using plain language, especially when the community includes people for whom English is not their first language.

Comment: @mbeckish: The answer states that `unknown` is not `true`. The answer does not state that `unknown` is `not true` :)